# Random forest regression model - not sure how to interpret (value lower than anticipated)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, random-forest

I am using a random forest regression model on the following data.

However, the R-squared value I get is **-0.22**, which seems very low.

```
rsquaredscores = [] 
x = correcteddf[['sleepiness_resolution_index']]
y = correcteddf[['distance']]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,train_size=0.7,random_state=0)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100,random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
rsquaredscore = r2_score(y_test,y_pred)
rsquaredscores.append(rsquaredscore)
print(rsquaredscores)
```

When I use the same data in a linear regression model:

```
resultmodeldistancevariation2sleep = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary = resultmodeldistancevariation2sleep.summary()
print(resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary)
```

I get a much higher R-squared value: **0.027**.

Is it normal for one of these values to be positive and one to be negative? Am I right in saying that the negative value basically indicates very poor model fit? Or am I going wrong somewhere?

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

```
correcteddf['sleepiness_resolution_index'].head(10)

    sleepiness_resolution_index
0   0.555556
1   1.500000
3   1.000000
6   0.900000
7   0.857143
8   0.875000
9   0.300000
10  0.750000
12  1.400000
13  2.333333

correcteddf[['distance']].head(10)

    distance
0   -0.251893
1   0.072180
3   -0.555438
6   0.199593
7   -0.378295
8   -0.162809
9   -0.108010
10  0.162275
12  -0.007996
13  4.637838
```

Comment: Questions asking about the interpretation of a model are better asked on [Cross Validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since these are statistics / ml questions, not coding questions.

Comment: An R-squared cannot be negative